# How does Google track the usage of a google map without a key

Tags: google-maps

I am using a google map in one on my web pages using the following api call.  Since I don't provide a key how would Google know whether or not I'm exceeding the usage limit set by Google.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't provide a Key, the limits are set on client side. That means that when a client connect to your web and use (for instance) reverse geocode, google tracks the amount a querys on their server made by your client IP, and after a certain limit doesn't responde any more to client request (at least for 24 hours), Then those limits are reset and the proccess reapeat. For reverse geocode the limit are 2000 geocode dayly by client IP. If you do provide a key, the limit is 200000 by server host.

Comment: Thank you eric pap.  This is a good answer.  The Client IP for tracking/monitoring is what I was thinking of.  This makes sense.

Comment: Ok. If fully answer you question, please remember to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I've just marked it as correct answer.